# Cassandra update with counters in C#

Tags: c#, cassandra

I want to increment useing a table with Counters. So i got the following table:

> create table counterInt (MeterID int, DayStamp timestamp, NumberOfValues counter, Value1 counter, Value2 counter, qualityScore counter, PRIMARY KEY((MeterID), DayStamp))

Also i have a list of objects and I fill the object list and iterate through it

```
 public void insertBasic(List<CSVMeter> meterList)
    {
        try
        {
            Connect();
            var statement = session.Prepare("Update counterInt SET NumberOfValues = NumberOfValues + ?, Value1 = Value1 + ?, Value2 = Value2 + ?, QualityScore = QualityScore + ?, ID, DayStamp, ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (CSVMeter meter in meterList)
            {
                var bind = statement.Bind( meter.NumberOfValues, meter.Value, meter.Value2, meter.qualityScore, meter.MeterID, meter.PeriodStart);
                var resultSetFuture = session.ExecuteAsync(bind);
                tasks.Add(resultSetFuture);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            CloseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

this is my object in C#

```
    public CSVMeter(int meterID, DateTime periodStart, double value, double value2, int numberOfValues, double qualityScore)
    {//getters setters that kind of stuff nothing weird}
```

Why do i get the following error and how can i resolve it? Also, can i use the prepared statements like that in this example?

> An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.SyntaxError' occurred in counterTest.exe
>   Additional information: line 1:136 no viable alternative at input ',' (...= QualityScore + ?, ID[,]...)

Also side question: is it possible to increment with doubles instead of integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you: you have a syntax error in your cql command.

For an `UPDATE` command you should use a `WHERE` clause and you should not use `VALUE` clause.

Watch your query carefully, it looks like you merged an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` command.